# How to segment characters and words from images into contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

I have a few contour images on which I want to do segmentation which basically means I want to save all characters in a contour image into individual images. But I am getting several noise images along with the required output. I want to know how to remove all the noise images without affecting the required output.

I was trying to change the values of `w` and `h`, so that I can minimize the noise and get only characters as segmented images.

```py
def imageSegmentation(fldr):
        for file in fldr:
            for f in os.listdir(file):
                im = cv2.imread(file+f)
                #print(f)
                imgray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
                contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
                con_img=cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,0,0), 1)
                #cv2.imshow("Contour_Image",con_img)
                #cv2.waitKey(0)
                #cv2.destroyAllWindows()

                newfolder=file+"\\contour\\"+f+"\\"
                os.makedirs(newfolder, exist_ok=True)
                fname=os.path.splitext(f)[0]
                cv2.imwrite((newfolder+fname+".png"),con_img)
                #cv2.imshow("con_img",con_img)
                #cv2.waitKey()
                #cv2.destroyAllWindows()

                newfolder2=file+"\\seg\\"+fname+"\\"
                os.makedirs(newfolder2,exist_ok=True)
                sorted_ctrs = sorted(contours, key=lambda cntr: cv2.boundingRect(cntr)[0])

                for i, cntr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
                    # Get bounding box
                    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)

                    # Getting ROI
                    roi = im[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                    #roi=~roi

                    if w > 9 and h > 27:
                        cv2.imwrite(newfolder2+"{}.png".format(i), roi)
```

I want to know how to only get correct characters images excluding the noise images in output folder. I have added a few of my input contour images which I need to segment into individual characters.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have few images of words which i want to segment into individual character images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336142) Is that question substantially different from your previous one except the other input images?

Comment: @HansHirse This program is completely different....

Comment: @Ani, do you want to obtain individual characters or an entire word? For instance, `narasimha` or each individual letter.

Comment: @nathancy I want individual characters like n, a, r, and so on...

Comment: @nathancy your code doesn't work for few of the images properly and i want a dynamic code lets say if i got any new image in that case i don't need to make changes to original code.It should work for all character size image perfectly.

Comment: @Ani, you may have to train your own classifier or neural network to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question is not completely clear if you wanted to extract individual characters or whole words, here is the approach to do both.

**Individual characters**

The main idea here is

- Convert image to grayscale and gaussian blur
- Perform canny edge detection
- Find contours
- Iterate through contours and filter using a minimum area
- Obtain bounding boxes and extract ROI

Canny edge detection using `cv2.Canny()`

[image]

Now we iterate through contours using `cv2.findContours()` and filter using `cv2.contourArea()` then draw bounding boxes
[image]

Here's the results for some of your other input images

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 120, 255, 1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

min_area = 100
image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > min_area:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
        image_number += 1

cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Whole words**

Now if you want to extract whole words, you have to modify the strategy a bit

- Convert image to grayscale and gaussian blur
- Perform canny edge detection
- Dilate to obtain a single contour
- Find contours
- Iterate through contours and filter using a minimum area
- Obtain bounding boxes and extract ROI

Canny edge detection

[image]

Dilate using `cv2.dilate()` to connect contours

[image]

Find bounding boxes and filter using contour area

[image]

Extracted ROI

[image]

Note: If you're trying to find whole words, you may have to change the minimum area value since it's dependent on the image you're analyzing.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 120, 255, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, kernel, iterations=5)
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

min_area = 5000
image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > min_area:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
        image_number += 1

cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```